# I'm working on pagination for my project. How do I get the number of records per page through user selection from drop-down option?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm working on a project. I have a drop-down option where a user can select any number of rows to display on a table. What I've done so far allows user selection and loads the table correctly but during navigation, the default number on the drop-down returns to "10". The problem now is that I want whatever value the user selects for the number of rows to display to stay selected during the navigation to the remaining rows of the table.(i.e if the user selects "10", the number of rows to display should be 10 through out navigating the page, or if it is "15" or "20" or "25" etc)
Below are what I have done so far... thanks for your help in advance!

```
<form name="frmCheck" method="post">
        <label class="clabel" for="rowno">Number of Rows:</label>
        <select class="name" id="rowno" name="rowno">
            <option value='all' hidden disabled>All</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
            <option value='15'>15</option>
            <option value='20'>20</option>
            <option value='25'>25</option>
            <option value='30'>30</option>
        </select>

<?php
    $currentpage = isset($_GET['currentpage']) ? $_GET['currentpage'] : 1;

                $rowno = $_POST['rowno'] ?? 10;
                $no_of_records_per_page = $rowno;
                $startfrom = ($currentpage - 1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

                //get total number of records in database
                $sqlcount = "SELECT *FROM cusregtbl";
                $stmt = $con->prepare($sqlcount);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
                $totalpages = ceil($num_rows/$no_of_records_per_page);
                
                //query for pagination
                $sqllimit = "SELECT *FROM cusregtbl LIMIT $startfrom, $no_of_records_per_page";
                            if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sqllimit))
                            {
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                                $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
                                if ($num_rows>0)
                                {
                                    echo "<table id='t01'' class='viewtbl' width='100%'>
                                    <tr id='tblhead'>
                                    <th class='th'>Account Number</th>
                                    <th class='th'>Customer Name</th>
                                    <th class='th'>Residence Type</th>
                                    <th class='th'>Customer Address</th>
                                    <th class='th'>Email Address</th>
                                    </tr>";
                                    while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
                                    {
                                        $accno = $rows['AccountNo'];
                                        $name = $rows['Fullname'];
                                        $restype = $rows['ResidenceType'];
                                        $adrs = $rows['CustomerAddress'];
                                        $email = $rows['Email'];
                                        
                                        // output data of each row
                                        echo "<tr>
                                        <td class='th'>". $accno."</td>
                                        <td class='th'>". $name."</td>
                                        <td class='th'>" . $restype. "</td>
                                        <td class='th'>" . $adrs. " </td>
                                        <td class='th'>". $email. "</td>
                                        </tr>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</table>";

                                    if($currentpage >= 2)
                                    {
                                        echo "<a class='nav_a' href='viewreg.php?currentpage=".($currentpage - 1)."'>-Previous-</a>";
                                    }

                                    for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++)
                                    {
                                        if($i == $currentpage)
                                        {
                                            echo '<a class="nav_a" href = "viewreg.php?currentpage='.$i.'">'."| ".$i."  ".'</a>';
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo '<a class="nav_a" href = "viewreg.php?currentpage='.$i.'">'."| ".$i."  ".'</a>';
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if($currentpage < $totalpages)
                                    {
                                        echo "<a class='nav_a' href='viewreg.php?currentpage=".($currentpage + 1)."'>-Next-</a>";
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                echo "Oops! No records found.";
                                }
                            }
        }
      ?>
//javascript code for select option
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php
            printf("let rownum='%s'", empty($_POST['rowno']) ? 0 : $_POST['rowno']);
            ?>

            let myForm=document.forms.frmCheck;
            let mySelect=myForm.rowno;
            let myCheck=myForm.check;
            
            if(rownum)
            {
                if(rownum=='all') myCheck.checked=true;
                Array.from(mySelect.querySelectorAll('option')).some(option=>
                {
                    if(rownum==Number(option.value) || rownum=='all')
                    {
                        option.selected=true;
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
                    
            // listen for changes on the checkbox
            myCheck.addEventListener('click',function(e)
            {
                if(myCheck.checked)
                {

                    var msg = confirm('Do you really want to see all of the \nrows? For a big table this could crash \nthe browser.');
                    if(!msg)
                    {
                        myCheck.checked=false;
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                if(mySelect.firstElementChild.value=='all')
                {
                    mySelect.firstElementChild.selected=this.checked;
                    mySelect.firstElementChild.disabled=!this.checked;
                }
                myForm.submit();
            });

            // listen for changes on the select  
            mySelect.addEventListener('change',function(e)
            {
                if(myCheck.checked) myCheck.checked=false;
                
                myForm.submit();
            });
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selected attribute.

```
<?php 
$rowno = isset($_POST['rowno'])?$_POST['rowno']:10;
if($rowno == 10) $rowno = isset($_GET['limit'])?$_GET['limit']:10;
?>
    <select class="name" id="rowno" name="rowno" onchange="window.location='viewreg.php?limit='+this.value+'&currentpage=1'">
        <option value='all' hidden disabled>All</option>
        <option value='10' <?=$rowno==10?'selected':''?>>10</option>
        <option value='15' <?=$rowno==15?'selected':''?>>15</option>
        <option value='20' <?=$rowno==20?'selected':''?>>20</option>
        <option value='25' <?=$rowno==25?'selected':''?>>25</option>
        <option value='30' <?=$rowno==30?'selected':''?>>30</option>
    </select>
```

Add limit parameter:

```
if($currentpage >= 2)
{
    echo "<a class='nav_a' href='viewreg.php?limit=".$rowno."&currentpage=".($currentpage - 1)."'>-Previous-</a>";
}

for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++)
{
    if($i == $currentpage)
    {
        echo '<a class="nav_a" href = "viewreg.php?limit='.$rowno.'&currentpage='.$i.'">'."| ".$i."  ".'</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a class="nav_a" href = "viewreg.php?limit='.$rowno.'&currentpage='.$i.'">'."| ".$i."  ".'</a>';
    }
}

if($currentpage < $totalpages)
{
    echo "<a class='nav_a' href='viewreg.php?limit=".$rowno."&currentpage=".($currentpage + 1)."'>-Next-</a>";
}
```

Summary:

```
<form name="frmCheck" method="post">
    <label class="clabel" for="rowno">Number of Rows:</label>
<?php 
$rowno = isset($_POST['rowno'])?$_POST['rowno']:10;
if($rowno == 10) $rowno = isset($_GET['limit'])?$_GET['limit']:10;
?>
    <select class="name" id="rowno" name="rowno" onchange="window.location='viewreg.php?limit='+this.value+'&currentpage=1'">
        <option value='all' hidden disabled>All</option>
        <option value='10' <?=$rowno==10?'selected':''?>>10</option>
        <option value='15' <?=$rowno==15?'selected':''?>>15</option>
        <option value='20' <?=$rowno==20?'selected':''?>>20</option>
        <option value='25' <?=$rowno==25?'selected':''?>>25</option>
        <option value='30' <?=$rowno==30?'selected':''?>>30</option>
    </select>

<?php
    $currentpage = isset($_GET['currentpage']) ? $_GET['currentpage'] : 1;

    $no_of_records_per_page = $rowno;
    $startfrom = ($currentpage - 1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

    //get total number of records in database
    $sqlcount = "SELECT *FROM cusregtbl";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sqlcount);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
    $totalpages = ceil($num_rows/$no_of_records_per_page);
    
    //query for pagination
    $sqllimit = "SELECT *FROM cusregtbl LIMIT $startfrom, $no_of_records_per_page";
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sqllimit))
    {
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
        if ($num_rows>0)
        {
            echo "<table id='t01'' class='viewtbl' width='100%'>
            <tr id='tblhead'>
            <th class='th'>Account Number</th>
            <th class='th'>Customer Name</th>
            <th class='th'>Residence Type</th>
            <th class='th'>Customer Address</th>
            <th class='th'>Email Address</th>
            </tr>";
            while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $accno = $rows['AccountNo'];
                $name = $rows['Fullname'];
                $restype = $rows['ResidenceType'];
                $adrs = $rows['CustomerAddress'];
                $email = $rows['Email'];
                
                // output data of each row
                echo "<tr>
                <td class='th'>". $accno."</td>
                <td class='th'>". $name."</td>
                <td class='th'>" . $restype. "</td>
                <td class='th'>" . $adrs. " </td>
                <td class='th'>". $email. "</td>
                </tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

            if($currentpage >= 2)
            {
                echo "<a class='nav_a' href='viewreg.php?limit=".$rowno."&currentpage=".($currentpage - 1)."'>-Previous-</a>";
            }

            for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++)
            {
                if($i == $currentpage)
                {
                    echo '<a class="nav_a" href = "viewreg.php?limit='.$rowno.'&currentpage='.$i.'">'."| ".$i."  ".'</a>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<a class="nav_a" href = "viewreg.php?limit='.$rowno.'&currentpage='.$i.'">'."| ".$i."  ".'</a>';
                }
            }

            if($currentpage < $totalpages)
            {
                echo "<a class='nav_a' href='viewreg.php?limit=".$rowno."&currentpage=".($currentpage + 1)."'>-Next-</a>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Oops! No records found.";
        }
    }
?>

//javascript code for select option
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php printf("let rownum='%s'", empty($_POST['rowno']) ? 0 : $_POST['rowno']); ?>

        let myForm=document.forms.frmCheck;
        let mySelect=myForm.rowno;
        let myCheck=myForm.check;
        
        if(rownum)
        {
            if(rownum=='all') myCheck.checked=true;
            Array.from(mySelect.querySelectorAll('option')).some(option=>
            {
                if(rownum==Number(option.value) || rownum=='all')
                {
                    option.selected=true;
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
                
        // listen for changes on the checkbox
        myCheck.addEventListener('click',function(e)
        {
            if(myCheck.checked)
            {

                var msg = confirm('Do you really want to see all of the \nrows? For a big table this could crash \nthe browser.');
                if(!msg)
                {
                    myCheck.checked=false;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if(mySelect.firstElementChild.value=='all')
            {
                mySelect.firstElementChild.selected=this.checked;
                mySelect.firstElementChild.disabled=!this.checked;
            }
            myForm.submit();
        });

        // listen for changes on the select  
        mySelect.addEventListener('change',function(e)
        {
            if(myCheck.checked) myCheck.checked=false;
            
            myForm.submit();
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Checked @Nikita but the problem still persists. If I select '15' and navigate to the next page, the value on the drop-down returns to '10'

Comment: @Ndongesit Edet Oh, sorry. href is 'get' method and you need to add limit parameter to it. I've updated code. Please check it again.

Comment: The other parts of the code don't relate to this.

Comment: @NdongesitEdet, Will you check the code again?

Comment: Ok@Nikita, I've edited the code with your lastest solution. It has a little progress. So, I have 21 records in the database. I selected 15 from the drop-down, 15 stays selected on the drop-down and 15 records are displayed on table but when I click next, 10 more records get displayed as the last instead of the 6 that remained.

Comment: Use offset in your query.

Comment: I've used offset, $startfrom=($currentpage-1)*$no_records_per_page; Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Oh, I found it. You need to reload page when select option changes.

Comment: @NdongesitEdet, I've updated code again. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nikita, problem solved. You just made my morning great.